# Rebus Puzzle - House Burning

Tags: rebus

My first rebus! This rebus is kind of difficult and is based on a weird property of English.

```
HOUSE
  B
  U
  R
  N
  I
  N
  G
while
  G
  N
  I
  N
  R
  U
  B
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why this puzzle got some downvotes. It looks like a good rebus to me, and the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be

> **"The house was burning up while it was burning down"**
>
>   where "burning up" and "burning down" both mean to be destroyed by heat/fire

Comment: Nice, this was based on this weird thing my friend told me.